# How can I format and sort date in descending order stored in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am getting ascending order and cant seem to figure out. I am using datatables and I can sort the result in front end but I would like to avoid that.

I am using Node.js express framework. Model for date looks like

```
var trackerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

description: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please add an description']
},
createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: 'User'
}
```

});

mongoose.model('Tracker', trackerSchema);

It is stored in MongoDB in the format - `createdAt : 2020-07-24T00:00:00.000+00:00`

Here is the controller code

```
Tracker.aggregate([
    
    {
        $sort: {
            createdAt: -1,
        },
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            user: 1,
            createdAt: {
                $dateToString: {
                    format: "%m-%d-%Y",
                    date: "$createdAt",
                },
            },
        },
    },
])
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
let sorted = await Tracker.find({}).sort({createdAt:-1});
```

Also, you need not define the `createdAt` manually. Just add the `{timestamps : true}` option in your schema, `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields will be automatically generated for each document.

Comment: I forgot to mention I cannot use simple find query. Query above also look for user record. Please check the model I am storing user record in Tracker model.